# Notification icon that looks like "S" inside a square

Tags: notification-icons

[image]

I am talking to my kid thru WeChat, so I am familiar with the WeChat logo message notification. But I don't know what that S in a square logo is.

What application is that?

Comment: This phone looks like a jailbroken and customized iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know. But you can swipe down the notifications bar to see what app is showing that icon. It will also have a notification in the tray.

Comment: Yeah.. But its my kids phone.. So i wont have access to it. Just would like to ask if your familiar with that. We are far apart actually.

Answer (score 0):

The icon is a Screenshot (Screen grab) app notification icon. So I guess there is nothing to worry about.